# Hide the Menu Button in new API21 Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm upgrading my app to support new Google APIs.
I've been playing for a while with new Toolbars but I still can't get how to make the menu button disappears when a Drawer Layout is opened.

Reference from the Material Design page (I'm trying to achieve the one on the right):
[Radial Action](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html#responsive-interaction-responsive-interaction-examples)

I'm not trying to "replace" the button like the example but to hide it temporary with an animation.
Any suggestion would be much appreciated! Thanks